# sub query in SELECT line

Tags: mysql

am trying to produce a list of ACTION records with fields from EVENTSTOCKLINK if they exist
my query used to look like

```
SELECT 
  action.actionid,
  partex.stockmake AS partexmake, 
  partex.stockmod AS partexmod
FROM
  ACTION 
  INNER JOIN EVENT 
    ON action.eventid = event.eventid 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT registrationnumber,stockmake,stockmod,stocktran,eventid 
    FROM eventstocklink 
  LEFT JOIN stock ON stock.stockid = eventstocklink.stockid 
WHERE statusid = '5'
GROUP BY eventstocklink.eventid
) AS partex 
ON partex.eventid = event.eventid 
WHERE actiondate2 BETWEEN 20130601 
  AND 20131031 
  AND event.siteid = 1 
  AND action.typeid = 1
```

this query takes >4 secs - so following advice from [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379624/slow-count-query-explain-shows-temp-and-filesort) I have been running
sub queries in the SELECT line and can reduce runtime by creating the query like this

```
SELECT action.actionid,
 (SELECT stockmake FROM eventstocklink
  LEFT JOIN stock ON stock.stockid = eventstocklink.stockid 
  WHERE statusid = '5' AND eventstocklink.eventid = event.eventid
 GROUP BY eventstocklink.eventid) partexmake,
 (SELECT stockmod FROM eventstocklink
  LEFT JOIN stock ON stock.stockid = eventstocklink.stockid 
  WHERE statusid = '5' AND eventstocklink.eventid = event.eventid
 GROUP BY eventstocklink.eventid) partexmod
FROM
  ACTION 
  INNER JOIN EVENT 
    ON action.eventid = event.eventid 
WHERE actiondate2 BETWEEN 20130601 
  AND 20131031 
  AND event.siteid = 1 
  AND action.typeid = 1
```

is this the best way to structure this query - I would like to include more fields from STOCK table
that have "statusid=5"

Comment: In the absence of aggregating functions, the use of a GROUP BY clause is inappropriate and (possibly) inefficient - and subqueries in the SELECT are probably a bad idea - although I don't have hard data for that.

Comment: Your first query looks like a better basis. It avoids correlated sub queries which tend to perform poorly (as for each correlated query it is having to perform a select for every line returned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You new query has correlated sub queries which tend to perform badly, while I am not sure the subquery is necessary in your original query.

Knowing the indexes of your tables would help as I suspect those are the real reasons your current query struggles (eg, is there an index on eventstocklink.eventid).

Try something like this:-

```
SELECT 
  action.actionid,
  MAX(partex.stockmake) AS partexmake, 
  MAX(partex.stockmod) AS partexmod
FROM ACTION 
INNER JOIN EVENT 
ON action.eventid = event.eventid 
LEFT JOIN eventstocklink
ON eventstocklink.eventid = event.eventid
LEFT JOIN stock 
ON stock.stockid = eventstocklink.stockid 
AND stock.statusid = '5'
WHERE actiondate2 BETWEEN 20130601 AND 20131031 
AND event.siteid = 1 
AND action.typeid = 1 
GROUP BY action.actionid
```

This does assume they you are not really that bothered which stockmake or stockmod are returned if there are multiple matching ones (as your existing queries do not attempt to define which ones are returned).

Comment: TQ - query runs v fast and results are perfect, didnt realise you could LEFT JOIN with condition this way

Comment: A condition like this on a left join is pretty useful much of the time when you want records which have a particular record on the left joined table, and if not you still want the record but with no matching columns. There is also nothing to stop you putting the checks for siteid and typeid from the WHERE clause into the first ON clause instead (although pretty pointless).